# Palete for Eclipse Web Page Editor not showing HTML5

Tags: eclipse, html, palette

I have installed the eclipse Web Page Editor in Eclipse Helios R.2 but when I open a file with this editor I can see in the palete only HTML 4.0 items.

Also they have no custom icon but a  < >  icon all of them.

¿How can I have HTML5 items on palete and icons on them?